# How many threads do I need to assign for a chat client?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, chat, webcam

I am creating a chat client which will allow the users to use their webcam and send their video. This is a LAN based software. There will be no voice chat, only video and text.

Also, along with group chat there can be a one-to-one chat which will allow user to use webcam. No webcam in conference chat. There will also be file sharing.

How many threads will I need to assign in all, assuming that the max allowed users at a time is 100 ?

How do I manage the ports? I mean, assigning, de-assigning, etc

*My initial guess is that I will need one thread between client and server for conference text chat, 1 thread for one-to-one text chat, 1 thread per user who starts a webcam. 1 thread per one-to-one chat for file sharing and n-threads for file sharing in conference where n is the nuimber of users connected at a time*

Comment: Will there be a central server handling everything or is each client connected to every other client?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis there will be a central server that will listen for client connections, keep a `Vector` containing all connected ports. When a user connects, a thread will be created and the `Vector` will be handed down to the thread. Then, the messages sent will be broadcasted to all connected sockets by the newly created thread. So basically, it is a centralized system :)

Comment: I would expect that you'd at need at most 3 threads per client; one to listen for incoming traffic, maybe one to handle outgoing traffic, and one for the rendering of the client.  This is of course only concerning the client, not the server.  The server could probably also manage with three threads; one to listen for all client communication, one for dispatching, and one to process the logic of the server (sanitation, authorization, etc.)

Comment: @Haz and three ports, one for chat, one for file IO and one for webcam ? :)

Comment: If your server is able to distinguish between the different types of traffic, then I think you should be able to use one port for all of it.  Listening on a port is blocking, at least with the regular Java Socket API, so you would need multiple threads if you're listening on multiple ports.

Comment: @Haz 3 ports is not a lot so it will keep it simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that you go with java for client implementation you can use one thread per user for the group chat, and one thread for each one to one connection, if you want p2p connections(you could do initial handshake through server for security reasons and then proceed in p2p mode).

If you plan to use websocket and web client there can't be p2p since browsers can only initiate websocket connection, but not accept. To use one channel per client you could tag you outgoing packets for content type and decode them appropriately. This scheme easy implemented in netty, where you can put you protocol implementation on top of TCP\IP socket. Also since netty is async you could gain some speed improvements due NIO